# Finding the $x^n$ coefficient of the power series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+3}}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have a practice test question that asks:

> Given the following Maclaurin series representation, $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+3}}{n!}$$ what is the coefficient of $x^n$?

I have the correct solution, but I do not know how to derive it. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You already have the coefficients of the power series, they're $0$ for $n$ not of the form $2m+3$ and $\frac{1}{m!}$ otherwise. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathbb{N}_0$ denote the nonnegative integers, and $a_n$ the coefficient desired.

$$a_n=\begin{cases} 0& \frac{n-3}{2}\notin \mathbb{N}_0\\ \frac{1}{\left(\frac{n-3}{2}\right)!} & \frac{n-3}{2}\in \mathbb{N}_0\end{cases}$$

Details added upon request.  If $n=2m+3$, then $m=\frac{n-3}{2}$.  If $m$ is an integer, we have a coefficient; otherwise we don't (and the coefficient is 0).

Comment: Thanks, that's the correct solution. Can you tell me how you got it?

Comment: Take @Alex's comment and solve for $m$.

Comment: after solving, just plug in for n?

Answer (score 3):

Remember, the $n$ in the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+3}}{n!}$ is a dummy variable; it doesn't matter what you call it.  The confusion is that you were given $n$ used in a different way.  So, change the index variable in the sum.

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+3}}{n!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k+3}}{k!}
$$

So, $x^n$ has a nonzero coefficient only if $n = 2k + 3$ for some $k$, which happens if $n$ is odd and $n\ge3$. And then, $k=\frac{n - 3}{2}$.